# Mounting a drive from an embedded device with bytes swapped

Tags: mount, partition, dd, storage

I have a device from about twenty years ago that uses an IDE hard drive as storage. I would like to keep using it, but it has a USB 1 interface that is extremely slow.

I can take out the hard drive and connect it to a USB 2.0 cable that is much faster, however getting access to the FAT32 data is not so straightforward.

I took a dd image of the first few megabytes of the drive connected each way and found that the only difference is a simple byte swap. I used the conv=swab option with dd and got an identical image. That is in hex:

```
ABCD = BADC
```

I was then able to mount the image with the loop  and offset options with mount. But this is a modified image, not direct to the device.

Is there a way to mount or process this device directly with this byte swapping built-in so that I don't have to extract/write the entire 20GB image each time to make changes?

Comment: I'll caution this: a twenty year old hard drive is past its expected life time. If you care about the data you want to store, it's a good idea to switch to a newer storage device. And: we're talking about 20 GB here. You can, right now, go out, go to a supermarket, and buy a new 32 GB USB stick. The [place where I buy my shampoo sells 32 GB sticks for 7,95€](https://www.dm.de/foto/fotozubehoer/usb-sticks-ladekabel-und-co). These aren't great sticks, but they're certainly going to be in better shape than a 20 year old hard drive, and way, way, way faster.

Comment: The IDE interface is what is important since this is an embedded device. None of this data cannot be easily replaced, being able to update the device quickly is what I am after.

Comment: Ah, so it's the embedded device that does the byte swapping, and not the IDE-to-USB1 adapter? (I was assuming the swapped data ended up on the device using USB, not from where the drive was installed)

Comment: (by the way, should you slightly feel at unease because you can never know when your IDE drive fails and where to get a new one: CompactFlash memory cards are also cheap, and directly do PATA as interface. So, a simple adapter between the connector sizes and you have a vibration-proof, low-power SSD instead of an IDE drive with spinning platters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CompactFlash#Technical_details )

Comment: That's right, I'm assuming the device has a different endianness and this is some design decision they took. When plugging it in directly through the device (USB 1 interface), it must internally correct this. The raw data on the HDD is swapped.

I have plenty of backup drives for when it eventually does die.

Comment: Good to hear you planned ahead! So, I'm not aware of a very direct way to achieve what you want, but two (three) routes come to mind: 1. write a small linux block device module that takes an underlying block device and does your endianness swap 2. Modify a userland FAT32 driver to do the byte swapping internally (3. do nothing different than you're currently doing and just plug your hard drive into a USB2 converter – 20 GB is not *that* much data, and with modern hard drive prices, maybe pulling a full backup each time might actually be a nice positive side effect?)

Comment: Re: 1. There's "network block device" in Linux, which essentially allows you to access anything as block device that a server allows you to access – that server can take the wrong-endianness original drive, and swap all accesses internally. You'd only need to write a nbd-plugin or nbd-filter for the server, [nbdkit](https://gitlab.com/nbdkit/nbdkit) ([man page](https://libguestfs.org/nbdkit.1.html), not a kernel driver, and you'd get your modified view at the data

Comment: This is certainly not the correct site for this answer, but did you consider a hardware solution? A simple flat ribbon cable with a male insulation displacement connector on one end and a female one on the other end, placed between drive and USB adapter. If I know the pin assignment correctly, you just need to separate pins 3–18 from the rest of the cable and flip it before mounting the second connector. Due to the strange pinout, this will result in a byte swap of the data bus: `1-2-18-17...4-3-19-20...`

Comment: @MarcusMüller would you consider writing the nbdkit part as an answer? You pointed me in the right direction.

I'm using the following command:
`nbdkit -n -r eval get_size='blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb' pread='dd conv=swab skip=$4 count=$3 iflag=count_bytes,skip_bytes if=/dev/sdb'`

Comment: @edbgon that's way more clever than what I would have done – I would've written a nb-filter in C! So, your solution is easier and more elegant. It should be you who writes that answer, and gets my upvote on it (you can make that answer as short as you like).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through a bit of trial and error and being pointed in the right direction by @MarcusMüller, the following command successfully mounted the drive in a read-write configuration. The performance seems a bit lacking, but it is still much better than the original USB 1 configuration.

```
nbdkit eval get_size='blockdev --getsize64 /dev/sdb' \
        pread='dd conv=swab skip=$4 count=$3 iflag=count_bytes,skip_bytes if=/dev/sdb' \
        pwrite='dd conv=swab seek=$4 oflag=seek_bytes of=/dev/sdb'
```

After this, I run `nbd-client localhost /dev/nbd0` and then mount the partition `/dev/nbd0p1` just as I would with a normal FAT32 drive.